# Javascript "unspecified error" in Open Layers

Tags: javascript, dictionary, openlayers

I am getting this error [alt text http://img239.imageshack.us/img239/6936/jserror.png](http://img239.imageshack.us/img239/6936/jserror.png) when the map loads.

The error is in the original, unmodified OpenLayers.js file on this line:

`return!!(document.namespaces);`

I have tried rewriting it to:

`return (typeof(document.namespaces) != 'undefined');`

and it worked but then I get same "unspecified" errors on further referrals to document.namespaces:

`if(!document.namespaces.olv){document.namespaces.add("olv",this.xmlns); ...`

I tried rewriting this to:

`if(typeof(document.namespaces.olv) == 'undefined') { ...`

but I get the same "unspecified error".

I only get this error on Internet Explorer (I tested on 7) and not in Firefox.

Any clues?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the solution.

The problem was that I was creating the map when the DOM was ready with Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  ... //create map here [WRONG]
```

All you have to do is to create the map after the onload event:

```
window.onload = function() { ... // create map here [CORRECT]
```

Comment: Overwriting all .onload events with yours is hardly a good thing to do

Comment: We had issues in Firefox with windows.onload, so opted instead for $(window).bind("load", function() {

Answer (score 7):

The real problem is that document.namespaces is not ready in IE8 sometimes when triggering $(document).ready (because of VML)

You can use instead :

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {} ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Internet Explorer is that when the page hits the document ready or the window onload, that M$ browser cannot determine the dimensions of the map canvas yet. If you want to work around this, you might also consider setting your map div dimensions:

```
<div id="map" style="width:250px;height:250px"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved my butt!  I only needed to explicitly set height, and not width, YMMV.